# Sqlalchemy ID field isn't populated when relationship with another table is set up

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to set up Sqlalchemy and am running into problems with setting up relationships between tables. Most likely it's misunderstanding on my part.

A table is set up like so. The important line is the one with two asterisks one either side, setting up the relationship to table "jobs."

```
class Clocktime(Base):
"""Table for clockin/clockout values

ForeignKeys exist for Job and Employee
many to one -> employee
many to one -> job
"""

__tablename__ = "clocktimes"
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
time_in = Column(DateTime)
time_out = Column(DateTime)
employee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employees.id'))
**job_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('jobs.id'))**
# employee = many to one relationship with Employee
# job = many to one relationship with Job

@property
def timeworked(self):
    return self.time_out - self.time_in

@property
def __str__(self):
    formatter="Employee: {employee.name}, "\
              "Job: {job.abbr}, "\
              "Start: {self.time_in}, "\
              "End: {self.time_out}, "\
              "Hours Worked: {self.timeworked}, "\
              "ID# {self.id}"
    return formatter.format(employee=self.employee, job=self.job, self=self)
```

**Now, the jobs table follows. Check the asterisked line:**

```
class Job(Base):
"""Table for jobs

one to many -> clocktimes
note that rate is cents/hr"""

__tablename__ = "jobs"
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(String(50))
abbr = Column(String(16))
rate = Column(Integer)  # cents/hr
**clocktimes = relationship('Clocktime', backref='job', order_by=id)**

def __str__(self):
    formatter = "Name: {name:<50} {abbr:>23}\n" \
                "Rate: ${rate:<7.2f}/hr {id:>62}"
    return formatter.format(name=self.name,
                            abbr="Abbr: " + str(self.abbr),
                            rate=self.rate/100.0,
                            id="ID# " + str(self.id))
```

When a user starts a new task, the following code is executed in order to write the relevant data to tables jobs and clocktimes:

```
new_task_job = [Job(abbr=abbrev, name=project_name, rate=p_rate), Clocktime(time_in=datetime.datetime.now())]
    for i in new_task_job:
        session.add(i)
    session.commit()
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    status = 1
```

Then, when the user takes a break...

```
new_break = Clocktime(time_out=datetime.datetime.now())
    session.add(new_break)
    session.commit()
```

If you look in the screenshot, the job_id field isn't being populated. Shouldn't it be populated with the primary key (id) from the jobs table, per

```
job_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('jobs.id'))
```

or am I missing something? I'm assuming that I'm to write code to do that, but I don't want to break anything that Sqlalchemy is trying to do in the backend. This should be a one job to many clocktimes, since a person can spend several days per task.

[image: Clocktimes Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking out the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html#relationships-backref) it 
looks like you've set up a collection of `ClockTime` objects on `Job` called `clocktimes` and a `.job` attribute on `ClockTime` that will refer to the parent `Job` object.

The expected behaviour is,

```
c1 = ClockTime()
j1 = Job()

>>> j1.clocktimes
[]
>>> print c1.job
None
```

When you populate `j1.clocktimes` with an object, you should also see `c1.job` get a non `None` value.

```
j1.clocktimes.append(c1)
>>> j1.clocktimes
[an instance of `ClockTime`]
>>> c1.job
[an instance of `Job`]
```

Do you find that behaviour? I don't see in your code where you populate `clocktimes` so the population of `job` is never triggered.

I think you are expecting the addition of `ForeignKey` to the column definition to do something it doesn't do.  The `ForeignKey` constraint you put on `job_id` simply means that it is constrained to be among the values that exist in the `id` column of the Jobs table.  Check [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html) for more details

Comment: You're right. I was expected a sort of 'join,' as it is called in the GIS world. Turns out, I need to write some code to set it up myself. I just wasn't entirely sure if it was supposed to be handled automatically via some magic or not and was hesitant to handle it myself and step on some functionality that was already supposed to be there.